# Angular 7 - forEach iteration inside of a promise is executing after the promise resolves. Why?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I created a service for some manipulation that needs to occur before prior to calling the drawPoll() function. I added console logs to keep track of the execution order and cannot figure out why the function chained to .then() is executing BEFORE the forEach iteration inside of the promise has finished. The whole point of creating the service and wrapping the forEach manipulation in the promise was so that I could be absolutely certain that the forEach iteration has completed before calling the drawPoll() function. What am I missing here?

**poll.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import nflPollTypes from '../../assets/types/poll-types-nfl.json';
import nflScoringTypes from '../../assets/types/scoring-types-nfl.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-poll',
  templateUrl: './poll.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./poll.component.scss']
})
export class PollComponent implements OnInit {
  chart:any;
  poll:any;
  votes:[] = [];
  labels:string[] = [];
  title:string = "";
  isDrawn:boolean = false;
  inputChoices:any = [];
  username:string = "";
  points:number;
  uid:string = "";
  votedChoice:string;
  hasVoted:boolean = false;
  scoringTypeString:string;
  nflPollTypes:any = nflPollTypes.types;
  nflScoringTypes:any = nflScoringTypes.types;

  @Input()
  pollKey: string;

  @Input()
  pollDocument:any;

  @Output()
  editEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Output()
  deleteEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const pollData:any = this.pollDocument.payload.doc;
    this.pollKey = pollData.id;
    this.poll = {
      id: this.pollKey,
      helperText: pollData.get("helperText"),
      pollType: pollData.get("pollType"),
      scoringType: pollData.get("scoringType"),
      user: pollData.get("user")
    };

    this.firebaseService.initPoll(this.pollKey, this.isDrawn, this.drawPoll).then((choices, votedChoice) => {
      this.poll.choices = choices;
      this.votedChoice = votedChoice;
      this.drawPoll();
    })
  }

  drawPoll() {
    console.log("DRAW!", this.poll);
    if (this.isDrawn) {
      this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.votes);
      this.chart.data.datasets[0].label = this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.text);
      this.chart.update()
    }
    if (!this.isDrawn) {
      this.inputChoices = this.poll.choices;
      var canvas =  <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById(this.pollKey);
      if(canvas) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'horizontalBar',
          data: {
            labels: this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.text),
            datasets: [{
              label: this.title,
              data: this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.votes),
              fill: false,
              backgroundColor: [
                "rgba(255, 4, 40, 0.2)",
                "rgba(19, 32, 98, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 4, 40, 0.2)",
                "rgba(19, 32, 98, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 4, 40, 0.2)",
                "rgba(19, 32, 98, 0.2)"
              ],
              borderColor: [
                "rgb(255, 4, 40)",
                "rgb(19, 32, 98)",
                "rgb(255, 4, 40)",
                "rgb(19, 32, 98)",
                "rgb(255, 4, 40)",
                "rgb(19, 32, 98)",
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            events: ["touchend", "click", "mouseout"],
            onClick: function(e) {
              console.log("clicked!", e);
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: this.title,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontColor: '#666'
            },
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  precision: 0
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        });
        this.isDrawn = true;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**firebase.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map, switchMap, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  // Source: https://github.com/AngularTemplates/angular-firebase-crud/blob/master/src/app/services/firebase.service.ts
  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  initPoll(pollKey, isDrawn, drawPollCallback) : any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let votedChoice;
      let choices = [];
      this.getChoices(pollKey).pipe(first()).subscribe(fetchedChoices => {
      fetchedChoices.forEach(choice => {
        const choiceData:any = choice.payload.doc.data();
        const choiceKey:any = choice.payload.doc.id;
        this.getVotes(choiceKey).pipe(first()).subscribe((votes: any) => {
          choices.push({
            id: choiceKey,
            text: choiceData.text,
            votes: votes.length,
            players: choiceData.players
          });
          let currentUserId = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
          let hasVoted = votes.filter((vote) => {
            return (vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.choice.stringValue == choiceKey) &&
            (vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.user.stringValue == currentUserId);
          });
          if (hasVoted.length > 0) {
            votedChoice = hasVoted[0].payload.doc._document.proto.fields.choice.stringValue;
          }
        });
        this.getVotes(choiceKey).subscribe((votes: any) => {
          if (isDrawn) {
            const selectedChoice = choices.find((choice) => {
              return choice.id == choiceKey
            });
            selectedChoice.votes = votes.length;
            drawPollCallback();
          }
        });
      });
      console.log("Done iterating");
    });
    resolve(choices, votedChoice)
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't play nicely with async.  [example](https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't fully understand which parts of your code are asynchronous and in what order parts of your code are getting executed.

**EDIT:** I assume that all observables in your code are asynchronous, i.e. they perform some kind of API calls in order to fetch needed data. They may be synchronous but your code really should not assume that. This will greatly reduce the risk of breaking something if the synchronous call later in the product life becomes asynchronous. **END EDIT**

So, Immediate problem you're asking about is that you resolve promise outside of the subscription - consequently before you go into the `forEach` loop. So, the timeline is like this:

- `PollComponent` calls `firebaseService.initPoll()`;
- `Promise` gets created and gets returned to the `PollComponent`;
- `PollComponent` subscribes to the promise;
- Lambda in the promise starts executing;
- You call for `getChoices()` observable, create some pipeline and subscribe to it, and I believe this is where your confusion starts: **`subscribe()` does not trigger any results immediately, and it does not wait for execution of whatever should have been executed in the observable pipeline and subscription lambda.** So, you've subscribed to the pipeline and immediately moved on with the code execution of the rest of promise lambda.
- Now, `Promise` gets resolved. Observable has not even started to do anything, but you've already resolved promise, which immediately triggers `then()` chain of subscriptions. This is when your `then()` lambda executes, and then everything cools down for a while.
- Then at some later time `Observable` emits an event which gets into your subscription and triggers `forEach` cycle, **but it's too late to emit whatever you wanted to get from the observable** because `Promise` has already been resolved.

But on the other hand, it looks like this is just one of the several things that happen out of sync in your code. For example, inside foreach you subscribe to `this.getVotes(choiceKey)` pipes twice, and the first subscription pushes something into the `choices` collection which is consumed by the second subscription - and again this is completely out of sync because they are not executed immediately when you call `subscribe()`. So, you need to chain calls in such a way so that later step could only occur after earlier one.

Now, remembering myself in this very position, the first thought is usually like this: "Ok then, I just need to rearrange my subscriptions and put later step subscription inside earlier step subscription". It's as obvious as it is wrong. :) The whole idea of Rx is that you should **only** subscribe to the end result of the whole pipeline which usually happens outside of the service that creates said pipeline. So, the correct way of rearranging your code is to build such a pipeline with the `pipe()`, `switchMap()`, `flatMap()`, `combineLatest()`, `merge()`, `map()` etc. Rx operators so that the whole thing would produce one single result that you really need in the end by moving through this pipeline in baby steps without explicit calling `subscribe()` on any single `Observable` you use there.

Also, you don't have to create `Promise` manually, there's actually a simple operator available on an observable exactly for this task.

I have no idea if this is correct code in your case or not, but the following is an idea of how you could rearrange your stuff using the described approach. I only hope it is clear enough to demonstrate how to replace subscriptions with different pipe operators in your case.

```
initPoll(pollKey, isDrawn, drawPollCallback) : any {

    return this.getChoices(pollKey).pipe(

        first(),

        // flatMap() replaces input value of the lambda
        // with the value that is emitted from the observable returned by the lambda.
        // so, we replace fetchedChoices array with the bunch of this.getVotes(choiceKey) observables
        flatMap((fetchedChoices: any[]) => {

            // here fetchedChoices.map() is a synchronous operator of the array
            // so we get an array of observables out of it and merge them into one observable
            // emitting all the values from all the observables in the array.
            return merge(fetchedChoices.map(choice => {
                const choiceKey: any = choice.payload.doc.id;
                return this.getVotes(choiceKey).pipe(first());
            })).pipe(toArray());
            // toArray() accumulates all the values emitted by the observable it is aplied to into a single array,
            // and emits that array once all observables are completed.

        }),

        // here I feel like you'll need to repeat similar operation
        // but by this time I feel like I'm already lost in your code. :)
        // So I can't really suggest what'd be next according to your code.
        flatMap((choices: any[]) => {
            return merge(choices.map(choice => {
                // ... other processing with calling some services to fetch different pieces of data
            })).pipe(toArray());
        }),

    // and converting it to the promise
    // actually I think you need to consider if you even need it at all
    // maybe observable will do just fine?
    ).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It's helping me somewhat understand better what is happening. I am approaching it step by step doing just one Observable at a time but on the first use of .pipe(toArray()) I get the following error core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...)(...).pipe is not a function. Do you know why this is?

Comment: property pipe does not exist on type operator function | observable document change action

Comment: What version of Rxjs do you use? Sounds like some old one. Or maybe function returns not observable, or you made some error in syntax, then please post the code you're trying. It should be there.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have enough of the source code to confirm the specific behavior of these functions, possibly `pipe` and certainly `subscribe` in the following code are pushing the `forEach` into asynchronous execution:

```
this.getChoices(pollKey).pipe(first()).subscribe(fetchedChoices => {
      fetchedChoices.forEach(choice => {...
```

`fetchedChoices => {fetchedChoices.forEach(...` is defining a callback function to the subscribe function, which will happen outside of the execution of the Promise executor function. `resolve(choices, votedChoice)` will execute immediately after the call to `subscribe` and before the callback passed to `subscribe`.  The `forEach` code is in the callback function to subscribe, and will be called asynchronously (and after the promise resolves).

Not *all* callbacks are executed asynchronously, but it is a good bet that if one is passed to a function named `subscribe`, it will be.